# Cant use stellargraph library from google colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, stellargraph

I have been trying to run a certain notebook in google colab with the use of stellargraph library
I am using this command to install stellargraph (required version is 1.2.1)

Note: I changed the python to 3.7.16

```
%pip install -q stellargraph[demos]==1.2.1
```

after that I try to import the library:

```
import stellargraph as sg
```

and I receive this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-ebd46f3ef3a7> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # verify that we're using the correct version of StellarGraph for this notebook
----> 2 import stellargraph as sg
      3 
      4 try:
      5     sg.utils.validate_notebook_version("1.2.1")

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stellargraph'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And after checking the existing modules with the command pip freeze or !pip list
I can see that the module is installed but still cant import it.

This is the notebook which I am trying to run: [notebook link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/stellargraph/stellargraph/blob/master/demos/link-prediction/node2vec-link-prediction.ipynb#scrollTo=igrUDtLJXFE3)

trying to install different versions of stellargraph and downgrading the python version on the google colab